# How do you make this corner smooth?

Tags: modeling

I have this square tube that takes a 90 degree corner, How would I go about making the outside of the corner smooth and rounded like the blue line.(The edges are beveled)

[image: Demonstration image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your current topology you could use the *Mesh: EdgeFlow* addon (available [here](https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/EdgeFlow)). Once enabled, select the edges and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Set Flow*, then tweak the *Iterations* parameter in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Or you could remove everything and instead select the 2 opposite edge loops and right click > *LoopTools > Bridge* (you first need to activate the LoopTools addon):

[image]

Then tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box* (*Segments* and *Strength*):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much

Comment: Just to be sure .. is [this](https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/EdgeFlow) the one ?  Maybe throw in the link?

Comment: Oh you're right, I thought it was a default addon